# How to get value of RadioGroup from different activity

Tags: java, radio-group

I making a fitness application in Android Studio and my projcet has Multiple Activities (6). I am trying to get the value of the radiogroup from the ThirdActivity in the SixthActivity. However, when I try to do this, I get the error:

```
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'int android.widget.RadioGroup.getCheckedRadioButtonId()' on a null object reference
```

I have made sure that all the names for the variables in the xml code are correct and am still running into the same problem.

> SixthActivity.java

```
  Intent intent=getIntent();
  String experience =intent.getStringExtra("Experience");
```

I would like to be able to get the value from thirdRadioGroup RadioGroup in ThirdActivity while being in the SixthActivity.

new code:

```
//ThirdActivity.class

 thirdRadioGroup = findViewById(R.id.thirdRadioGroup);
 int radioIdExperience = thirdRadioGroup.getCheckedRadioButtonId();
 experience = (RadioButton) findViewById(radioIdExperience);
 Intent intent = new Intent(this, SixthActivity.class);
 intent.putExtra("Experience", experience.getText());
 startActivity(intent);
```

Now, again this throw `NullPointerException`..

```
error: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.lang.CharSequence android.widget.RadioButton.getText()' on a null object reference
```

Comment: And a repost of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55321473/null-object-reference-on-radiogroup-variable-android-studio

Answer (score 1):

You are getting the null pointer exception because the ThirdActivity is paused. ThirdActivity  is paused because you have the Sixth one running. One way to get your data from the ThirdActivity is to pass them as extra intent values when navigating between them.
Example Java, you do this on the ThirdActivity

```
Intent intent = new Intent(ThirdActivity .this, SixthActivity.class);
intent.putExtra("Experience",experience.getText());
startActivity(intent);
```

In your sixth activity you receive the data like this:

```
Intent intent=getIntent();
String experience =intent.getStringExtra("Experience");
```

Comment: Would I need to pass the radiogroup value as an intent in ThirdActivity?

Comment: Yes, that is one way to do it.

Comment: @Kars Could you provide any pseudocode on how to do this? Anything would be greatly appreciated

Comment: Edited to provide a pseudocode example.

Comment: @bensadiku Thank you the pseudocode helps a lot. However, I am getting an error on the line intent.putExtra("Experience",experience.getText());. The error states : java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.lang.CharSequence android.widget.RadioButton.getText()' on a null object reference. In that line you state experience.getText() in ThirdActivity.java, but I created the experience button in the Sixth Activity. Am I to create the experience button in the thirdActivity now? I did that and received the error above.

Comment: What's the error? I just copied from your text.

Comment: @bensadiku I edited my comment to be more thorough

Comment: So my pseudo code assumes your radio buttons exist in the ThirdActivity only. Therefore the code `experience.getText()` is only meant to be ran on the Third Activity only. You should remove the old attempts/buttons from the sixth activity because as we discussed that is not possible and will produce null pointer exception.

Comment: @bensadiku That is what I did. I edited my original post to add the code you suggested if you want to take a look.

Comment: Two things:
1) Your edit doesn't reflect that you removed the radio button code from the sixth activity.
2) Does the radio button with the id `radioIdExperience` exist in the third activity? Is it being inflated properly?

Comment: @bensadiku I edited the original post. Sorry. And no, I don't have a radiobutton called radioIdExperience, that is an integer that holds the value of the radioGroup, isnt it?

Comment: Yes, each button needs to have an id
`experience = (RadioButton) findViewById(radioIdExperience);` this is wrong.
Should be `experience = (RadioButton) findViewById(R.id.radioIdExperience);`

Answer (score 0):

One way to pass values between activities is by using putExtra on the intent responsible for the new activity.

```
intent.putExtra("NAME", value)
```

You can then access the value by calling getExtra on the new activity.

```
getIntent().getIntExtra("NAME")
getIntent().getStringExtra("NAME")
```

https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent